# So long, and thanks for all the fish Nick Craver!

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks

Some folks tend to leave an indelible impression on the spaces they've been in, whether or not they're noticed. While admittedly, most of my interactions with Nick have been off the sites proper - whether they were awesome deep dives into the architecture of the network [on Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/Nick-Craver/) or on the old [Server Fault blog](https://blog.serverfault.com), or tweets that pack surprising numbers of insights.

I found out [a few days ago](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1427323097380794371) that he was leaving the company that he's helped shape for over a decade. I think we all wish him the best, and wherever he goes next has gotten a hell of a SRE, Dev and human being.

Comment: `git commit -S 135201 -v -m "All the best and thanks for all the fish, Nick!"`

Answer (score 28):

This is no doubt the end of an era.

Stack Exchange won't be the same without its chief programmer and Main Bug Fixer.

But I'm 100% sure Nick made sure to train others in his awesome ways, made sure SE hired skilled and dedicated developers like him, so I'm not worried about Stack Exchange. And I'm glad for Nick, as I'm also sure he won't be doing it without a really good reason.

So, farewell Mr. Craver, and thanks for all the juicy details you shared over the years! Your detailed bug fix explanations are what I remember the most, personally. And your awesome blog posts. :)

And here is my special gift for you!

> [image: confetti]

<kbd><3</kbd>

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for all of your hard work and goodwill you’ve shown over the years. These memories are ones that we’ll never forget.

> **From Nick Profile:**
>
>  “I design and build very fast things in hopes of making life easier for millions of developers”.

With skills like yours, you don't need luck — but good luck for your new journey.

Answer (score 7):

That is really very sad for all of us to say a good bye to you Nick Craver, the Main Bug Fixer. Thanks for solving so many of the bugs. You will always remain in our heart.

My exact reaction was:

[image]

Comment: Heh, it's from Chez Youpel closure notice.

Comment: He fixed them because he committed most of them :p

Comment: @DeanWard easy to blame those who can't defend themselves! :-D